# Coherence server in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-coherence

I am new to web-logic server and I have created a coherence server in web-logic. I connected to that server with JMX port but I am not getting any m-beans. Can any body explain how to configure coherence server in web-logic and also give me sample application that uses coherence.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/coherence_web_with_weblogic_server

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what version of WebLogic server you are using. I would STRONGLY recommend using WebLogic 12.1.2 because it has integrated [Coherence applications support](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLCOH/introduction.htm). If you want an overview of the Managed Coherence Servers (aka Coherence Container) feature in WebLogic, there is a also a [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuvmKnkQHeI).

If you install WebLogic 12.1.2 with examples, they contain a Coherence example with full WebLogic configuration. Tim Middleton has an excellent [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/OracleCoherence/entry/running_the_managed_coherence_servers) that walks you through the example.

Finally, the Coherence MBeans by default will be registered with the domain runtime MBean server, so you will see them on the Admin server. There are also new WebLogic configuration MBeans for configuring Managed Coherence Servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the admin server, not the coherence server. It becomes a little clearer when you use WLST to query MBeans, but most of the JMX data you want will be served from the admin server.

[This is a sample Coherence application that runs on Glassfish](http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2012/10/java-one-2012-slides-and-code.html). Oracle have made it quite easy to port Glassfish webapps over to Weblogic, but if you really want to learn how coherence works, I would suggest you take a look at the code and try to write your own application from scratch, using it as an example.